# Automatic line breaks on dots in method chains in ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper

With my current settings, ReSharper breaks a long line like this:

```
var attributes =
    GetType().GetMethod((string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]).GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof (AutomaticRedirectToViewAttribute), false);
```

I think it's better than not breaking the line at all, but breaking it at the dots of methods/properties makes more sense to me:

```
var attributes = 
    GetType()
    .GetMethod((string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"])
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (AutomaticRedirectToViewAttribute), false);
```

(It doesn't have to look *exactly* like this.) How can I setup ReSharper to do it this way? I haven't found such option in its settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-88220?projectKey=RSRP) hints at it not being possible with Resharper yet.

I seem to remember a forum post about it as well, but I can't find it.

Comment: This will be added at 7.1 (see http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/resharper-71-early-access-is-open/).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 it's works as you want it.

Which version are using?